# Just when is a stackoverflow fair and sensible?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, infinite

**Code updated**

For fixing the bug of a filtered `Interminable`, the following code is updated and merged into original:

```
public static bool IsInfinity(this IEnumerable x) {
    var it=
        x as Infinity??((Func<object>)(() => {
            var info=x.GetType().GetField("source", bindingAttr);
            return null!=info?info.GetValue(x):x;
        }))();

    return it is Infinity;
}
```

`bindingAttr` is declared a constant.

---

- **Summary**

  I'm trying to implement an *infinite enumerable*, but encountered something seem to be illogical, and temporarily run out of idea. I need some direction to complete the code, becoming a semantic, logical, and reasonable design.
- **The whole story**

  I've asked the question a few hours ago:

  [Is an infinite enumerable still "enumerable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703285/is-an-infinite-enumerable-still-enumerable)

  This might not be a good pattern of implementation. What I'm trying to do, is implement an enumerable to present infinity, in a logical and semantic way(I thought ..). I would put the code at the last of this post.

  The **big problem** is, it's just for presenting of infinite enumerable, but the enumeration on it in fact doesn't make any sense, since there are no real elements of it.

  So, besides provide dummy elements for the enumeration, there are four options I can imagine, and **three** lead to the `StackOverflowException`.

  1. Throw an `InvalidOperationException` once it's going to be enumerated.

     ```
     public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
         for(var message="Attempted to enumerate an infinite enumerable"; ; )
             throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
     }
     ```
  2. and 3. are technically equivalent, let the stack overflowing occurs when it's **really** overflowed.

     ```
     public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
         foreach(var x in this)
             yield return x;
     }
     ```

     ```
     public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
         return this.GetEnumerator();
     }
     ```
  3. (described in 2)
  4. Don't wait for it happens, throw `StackOverflowException` directly.

     ```
     public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
         throw new StackOverflowException("... ");
     }
     ```

The tricky things are:

If `option 1` is applied, that is, enumerate on this enumerable, becomes an *invalid operation*. Isn't it weird to say that *this lamp isn't used to illuminate*(though it's true in my case).

If `option 2` or `option 3` is applied, that is, we *planned* the stack overflowing. Is it really as the title, *just when stackoverflow is fair and sensible*? Perfectly logical and reasonable?

The last choice is `option 4`. However, the stack in fact does not really overflow, since we prevented it by throwing a **fake** `StackOverflowException`. This reminds me that when Tom Cruise plays John Anderton said that: "*But it didn't fall. You caught it. The fact that you prevented it from happening doesnt change the fact that it was going to happen.*"

Some good ways to avoid the illogical problems?

---

The code is compile-able and testable, note that one of `OPTION_1` to `OPTION_4` shoule be defined before compile.

- **Simple test**

  ```
  var objects=new object[] { };
  Debug.Print("{0}", objects.IsInfinity());
  var infObjects=objects.AsInterminable();
  Debug.Print("{0}", infObjects.IsInfinity());
  ```
- **Classes**

  ```
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Collections;
  using System;

  public static partial class Interminable /* extensions */ {
      public static Interminable<T> AsInterminable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> x) {
          return Infinity.OfType<T>();
      }

      public static Infinity AsInterminable(this IEnumerable x) {
          return Infinity.OfType<object>();
      }

      public static bool IsInfinity(this IEnumerable x) {
          var it=
              x as Infinity??((Func<object>)(() => {
                  var info=x.GetType().GetField("source", bindingAttr);
                  return null!=info?info.GetValue(x):x;
              }))();

          return it is Infinity;
      }

      const BindingFlags bindingAttr=
          BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic;
  }

  public abstract partial class Interminable<T>: Infinity, IEnumerable<T> {
      IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
          return this.GetEnumerator();
      }

  #if OPTION_1
      public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
          for(var message="Attempted to enumerate an infinite enumerable"; ; )
              throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
      }
  #endif

  #if OPTION_2
      public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
          foreach(var x in this)
              yield return x;
      }
  #endif

  #if OPTION_3
      public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
          return this.GetEnumerator();
      }
  #endif

  #if OPTION_4
      public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
          throw new StackOverflowException("... ");
      }
  #endif

      public Infinity LongCount<U>(
          Func<U, bool> predicate=default(Func<U, bool>)) {
          return this;
      }

      public Infinity Count<U>(
          Func<U, bool> predicate=default(Func<U, bool>)) {
          return this;
      }

      public Infinity LongCount(
          Func<T, bool> predicate=default(Func<T, bool>)) {
          return this;
      }

      public Infinity Count(
          Func<T, bool> predicate=default(Func<T, bool>)) {
          return this;
      }
  }

  public abstract partial class Infinity: IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter {
      partial class Instance<T>: Interminable<T> {
          public static readonly Interminable<T> instance=new Instance<T>();
      }

      object IFormatProvider.GetFormat(Type formatType) {
          return typeof(ICustomFormatter)!=formatType?null:this;
      }

      String ICustomFormatter.Format(
          String format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider) {
          return "Infinity";
      }

      public override String ToString() {
          return String.Format(this, "{0}", this);
      }

      public static Interminable<T> OfType<T>() {
          return Instance<T>.instance;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: "I'm trying to implement an infinite enumerable" - why? since you say yourself: "the enumeration on it in fact doesn't make any sense". So what use do you have for an *infinite enumerable*?

Comment: @Corak: To represent an infinite collection. Floating point numbers are defined `NegativeInfinity` and `PositiveInfinity`, but we don't *calculate* on them, right?

Comment: Where would you use that infinite collection?

Comment: An infinite enumerable of what? If you want something in particular (like the natural numbers) you can easily implement that using generators. If you just want to represent the concept of infinity, why not just create a class called "Infinity", or use something like double.Infinity?

Comment: @MartinEden: I've describe in my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703285/is-an-infinite-enumerable-still-enumerable; something like infinite points of intersection of two overlapping line segments, we just need to determine there are infinite points, but mostly do not enumerate. They are natural numbers, use of floating point numbers might not be necessary.

Comment: @MartinEden: On the other hand, if there are finite points(mostly one), something like `double.PositiveInfinity` cannot represent a *collection* of points. And I in fact, just as you say, created a `Infinity` class.

Comment: @Knaģis: Thank you for mentioning that. I've responded with the comments.

Comment: Wait, a *collection* is different from an *enumeration*. For example an `ICollection` has a `Count` property, whereas an `IEnumerable` does not. If you have infinite points of intersection, you can *enumerate* (i.e. go from one to the next) on them, you just can't *count* them.

Comment: @Corak: My Englishis poor, and might not expressed very well. What I mean is that, the actual enumeration is not for here, since those points can difinitely be calculated out. For this question, the problem is to present infinity. Intersection of line segments is just for example. Thanks for noticed that.

Comment: Still don't get the usefullness of an "infinite enumerable". The positive/negative Infinity is useful to determin "invalid" numbers (i.e. numbers you shouldn't work with). But an "infinite enumerable" is perfectly valid and you *can* work with it. For example this enumerable is "infinite" and perfectly valid: `public static IEnumerable<int> RandomEnumerable() { var rnd = new Random(); while (true) { yield return rnd.Next(); } }`

Comment: @Corak: In your example the behaving logic of the code is an *unibody*, that is, implementation detail and the enumerable are consisted. However, not all cases are like this. Sometimes the aspect of designing and implementation detail are seperated. I think the content of your comments are correct, there're just some different considerations in this question.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the abstract concept a sequence of (possibly) infinite number of items is very real and already accounted for in the implementation of `IEnumerable`. There is no difference in usage if an `IEnumerable` yields ten, a million or infinite number of items. You cannot know how many items there will be. And you probably shouldn't care. Except, when you want all at once (i.e. `.ToList()`). There is no way to do something like `if (!enumerable.IsInfinite()) { return enumerable.ToList(); }` and other than that i can't imagine any use for this. How would you use it?

Comment: @Corak: In this sense, yes. But the tricky thing is, ten or million or whatever as long as it's in a finite range, we know that to enumerate on it might be meaningful. Although the random enumerable of your example is infinite, but what we care in that case would be on each enumerated element.

Comment: @Corak: For this question, is to define a enumerable that is meant to **not enumerated**; to define the difference between the *meaningful enumeration* and the *non* one. That we can return an identical type of an enumerable, and we know which one needs to be enumerated -- we want the element; and which one is **not** -- we should prevent to enumerate on it.

Comment: @KenKin Why fine point that seems to be overlooked here, is that most infinite sets are *NOT* enumerable at all.  In fact, only countably infinite sets could be enumerable, even by the relaxed principals that you are employing.  So Integers or Rationals are enumerable, but, the Reals, or the infinite Point-Subsets of overlapping lines are not in any sense enumerable.

Comment: @KenKin No, you're missing my point.  If it's countably infinite, then the enumeration never ends.  But if it's *uncountably* infinite, then it can never even begin, because it is ***not possible*** to enumerate it, *even* with infinite time.  In other words, "countable", whether finite or infinite is the same thing as "enumerable" (*literally*, just look up the definition of "enumerate").  And thus "uncountable" must necessarily  also mean "not enumerable".

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Thank you very much. Since my previous comment is misled, I've deleted it. I think that you are perfectly correct that *enumeration of countably infinite never ends and enumeration of uncountably infinite can never begin*. And I think that I'm preventing the enumeration of either cases.

Comment: Isn't this related to the `halting problem`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the other post you linked, an infinite enumeration makes perfectly sense for C# to enumerate and there are an huge amount of real-world examples where people write enumerators that just do never end(first thing that springs off my mind is a random number generator).

So you have a particular case in your mathematical problem, where you need to define a special value (infinite number of points of intersection). Usually, that is where I use simple static constants for. Just define some static constant IEnumerable and test against it to find out whether your algorithm had the "*infinite number of intersection*" as result.

To more specific answer your current question: DO NOT EVER EVER cause a real stack overflow. This is about the nastiest thing you can do to users of your code. It can not be caught and will immediately terminate your process(probably the only exception is when you are running inside an attached instrumenting debugger).

If at all, I would use `NotSupportedException` which is used in other places to signal that some class do not support a feature(E.g. `ICollection`s may throw this in `Remove()` if they are read-only).

Comment: +! for don't throw `StackOverflow`.

Comment: Is there any nice way a code can detect that the available stack space is sufficiently low that it should throw an exception to avoid a stack overflow?  Some types of data-structure parsing are most conveniently handled using recursive algorithms, and it would seem nicer to have the maximum allowable depth vary with the amount of available stack space than to impose a hard depth limit which, depending upon the stack available when a method is called, may or may not curtail recursion before overflowing the stack.

Comment: @supercat I use this in DEBUG-only if you have a place where it "use to happen": `if (new StackTrace().FrameCount > 500) throw new StackOverflowException()`. Not elegant, but gets the job done ;). (Note, that you actually can catch manually thrown stack overflows. If it still looks scary, just replace the throw with whatever seems nice to you ;)). Of course, this ain't a generic solution, but only works if you have some function to place the line into.

Comment: I would conjecture that it's possible to blow the stack with a lot less than 500 frames, or to have 500 frames while the stack is less than 1% full.  As for what to call the exception, I think something like `StackLimitException` might be good.  If I had my druthers, such a thing would exist in the Framework for methods which declaratively requested stack-guarding code.  Alternatively, I'd allow a thread to specify a delegate which should run in a new thread if a stack overflow occurs [I can understand that an unexpected stack overflow may not be recoverable on the thread where it occurs...

Comment: ...and that having a thread die unexpectedly should be considered a Very Bad Thing, but having a delegate run in a new thread could resolve both issues.]

Comment: _I would conjecture that it's possible to blow the stack with a lot less than 500 frames, or to have 500 frames while the stack is less than 1% full._ Very true, I second that 100%. Please use my code ONLY for getting a quick debugging glimpse in places, where elsewhere debugging is horrible. Using 500 is not set in stone but just choosen as "some number which is very unlikely to happen and usually the stack is not blown yet". It's a general and neat quick-debug-trick to keep in your pocket belt - by all means, its not a production code stack overflow detection!

Comment: btw.. in normal and "local" applications, I use `Debugger.Break()` instead of `throw new StackOverflowException()` to directly get my debugger firing up.

Comment: @supercat: Thank you very much for thinking it deeply. Good discussion.

Answer (score 8):

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    while (true)
        yield return default(T);
}
```

This will create an infinite enumerator - a foreach on it will never end and will just continue to give out the default value.

Note that you will not be able to determine `IsInfinity()` the way you wrote in your code. That is because `new Infinity().Where(o => o == /*do any kind of comparison*/)` will still be infinite but will have a different type.

Comment: @KenKin filtered infinity can return either `0` (no match) a `distinct number` of values (known matches) or `infinite` matches (based upon a property, for example all odd numbers)

Comment: I've revised the code for fixing the problem mentioned in the answer, and now it would be `Infinity` even if filtered. Thank you very much, however, I would not be able to determine whether it's an infinite enumerable with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly -- *infinite* is a confusing word here. I think you need a *monad* which is either enumerable or not. But let's stick with *infinite* for now.

I cannot think of a nice way of implementing this in C#. All ways this could be implemented don't integrate with C# generators.

With C# [generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29), you can only emit valid values; so there's no way to indicate that this is an *infinite* enumerable. I don't like idea of throwing exceptions from generator to indicate that it is *infinite*; because to check that it is *infinite*, you will have to to *try-catch* every time.

If you don't need to support generators, then I see following options :

1. Implement *sentinel* enumerable:

   ```
   public class InfiniteEnumerable<T>: IEnumerable<T> {
       private static InfiniteEnumerable<T> val;

       public static InfiniteEnumerable<T> Value {
           get {
               return val;
           }
       }

       public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
           throw new InvalidOperationException(
               "This enumerable cannot be enumerated");
       }

       IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
           throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "This enumerable cannot be enumerated");
       }
   }
   ```

   Sample usage:

   ```
   IEnumerable<int> enumerable=GetEnumerable();

   if(enumerable==InfiniteEnumerable<int>.Value) {
       // This is 'infinite' enumerable.
   }
   else {
       // enumerate it here.
   }
   ```
2. Implement `Infinitable<T>` wrapper:

   ```
   public class Infinitable<T>: IEnumerable<T> {
       private IEnumerable<T> enumerable;
       private bool isInfinite;

       public Infinitable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
           this.enumerable=enumerable;
           this.isInfinite=false;
       }

       public Infinitable() {
           this.isInfinite=true;
       }

       public bool IsInfinite {
           get {
               return isInfinite;
           }
       }

       public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
           if(isInfinite) {
               throw new InvalidOperationException(
                   "The enumerable cannot be enumerated");
           }

           return this.enumerable.GetEnumerator();
       }

       IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
           if(isInfinite) {
               throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "The enumerable cannot be enumerated");
           }

           return this.enumerable.GetEnumerator();
       }
   }
   ```

   Sample usage:

   ```
   Infinitable<int> enumerable=GetEnumerable();

   if(enumerable.IsInfinite) {
       // This is 'infinite' enumerable.
   }
   else {
       // enumerate it here.
       foreach(var i in enumerable) {
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Infinite sequences may be perfectly iterable/enumerable. Natural numbers are enumerable and so are rational numbers or PI digits. Infinite is the opposite of finite, not enumerable.

The variants that you've provided don't represent the infinite sequences. There are infinitely many different infinite sequences and you can see that they're different by iterating through them. Your idea, on the other hand, is to have a singleton, which goes against that diversity.

If you have something that cannot be enumerated (like the set of real numbers), then you just shouldn't define it as IEnumerable as it's breaking the contract.
If you want to discern between finite and infinite enumerable sequences, just crate a new interface `IInfiniteEnumerable : IEnumerable` and mark infinite sequences with it.

Interface that marks infinite sequences

```
public interface IInfiniteEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
}
```

A wrapper to convert an existing `IEnumerable<T>` to `IInfiniteEnumerable<T>` (`IEnumerable`s are easily created with C#'s `yield` syntax, but we need to convert them to `IInfiniteEnumerable` )

```
public class InfiniteEnumerableWrapper<T> : IInfiniteEnumerable<T> {
    IEnumerable<T> _enumerable;

    public InfiniteEnumerableWrapper(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
        _enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Some infinity-aware routines (like calculating the sequence length)

```
//TryGetCount() returns null if the sequence is infinite
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static int? TryGetCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence) {
        if (sequence is IInfiniteEnumerable<T>) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return sequence.Count();
        }
    }
}
```

Two examples of sequences - a finite range sequence and the infinite Fibonacci sequence.

```
public class Sequences {
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetIntegerRange(int start, int count) {
        return Enumerable.Range(start, count);
    }

    public static IInfiniteEnumerable<int> GetFibonacciSequence() {
        return new InfiniteEnumerableWrapper<int>(GetFibonacciSequenceInternal());
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> GetFibonacciSequenceInternal() {
        var p = 0;
        var q = 1;
        while (true) {
            yield return p;
            var newQ = p + q;
            p = q;
            q = newQ;
        }
    }
}
```

A test app that generates random sequences and tries to calculate their lengths.

```
public class TestApp {
    public static void Main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            IEnumerable<int> sequence = GetRandomSequence();
            Console.WriteLine(sequence.TryGetCount() ?? double.PositiveInfinity);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Random _rng = new Random();
    //Randomly generates an finite or infinite sequence
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetRandomSequence() {
        int random = _rng.Next(5) * 10;
        if (random == 0) {
            return Sequences.GetFibonacciSequence();
        } else {
            return Sequences.GetIntegerRange(0, random);
        }
    }
}
```

The program output something like this:

```
20
40
20
10
20
10
20
Infinity
40
30
40
Infinity
Infinity
40
40
30
20
30
40
30
```

Comment: The question is for the case that if I have a method returns `IEnumerable<int>`, sometimes it returns a collection of finite enumerable `int`s, but sometimes the return value which is infinite.

Comment: As I've said, just mark the infinite sequences as IInfiniteEnumerable. `IEnumerable<int> GetSomeSequence() { return (new Random().NextDouble() > 0.5 ? GetFirst100Integers() : GetInfiniteFibonacciSequence() ); }` (`GetInfiniteFibonacciSequence()` returns `IIniniteEnumerable<int>`) and check for it where needed `var sequence = GetSomeSequence(); if(sequence is IInfiniteEnumerable<int>) { } else { }`

Comment: Maybe a revision of the answer for more understandable(with the comment)?